# Android sql query in endless loop Or service

Tags: android, view

I'm creating a simple news app. It has 3 parts.

1. Database which stores news (Id, category, headline)
2. A services which poll external sources at regular intervals for latest news and stores in db
3. A view which shows the latest news

From the drop down menu, if the user selects category "politics" a view is launched which will show news relates to politics and keep updating in real time (as soon as new news is inserted into the the database.)

I'm thinking of creating a services which will query the db every 2 sec and show the results in view.

Is there a native android function which will do this -- endlessly query db.
Any other better to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should seriously consider building a `ContentProvider` and a proper service layer. Querying your local database every 2 seconds is unnecessary; you should instead rely on `CursorLoader` and leverage the fact that it can requery whenever it is notified of a change to your data.

The basic structure is this:

- `CursorLoader` queries your `ContentProvider` for data using a Uri that maps to news article content.
- Some other class (probably a `Service` or an `IntentService`) is responsible for fetching news articles. Trigger this class however and whenever you like.
- When the article fetcher has new articles, it inserts them using the `ContentProvider`.
- When the `ContentProvider` modifies news articles in your database, it should call [`ContentResolver.notifyChange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver)) on the Uri that maps to news article content.
- The `CursorLoader` receives this notification and automatically requeries for you.

You should read the guides for [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), and maybe [Intent Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) as well.